# L.mapbox is undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

when i am trying to load mapbox Leaflet it gives an error.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
map = L.mapbox.map('map').addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {
        autocomplete: true
    }));
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.mapboxgl-popup {
    max-width: 400px;
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id='map' style="height: 660px"></div>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Loading adding mapbox to an id in document ready. Did anyone got this before. 
When i type L in browser console it must return something like this Object {version: "1.0.2", Util: Object, Mixin: Object, Browser: Object, DomUtil: Object…}, but it returns _cg {_ff: 0, bits: 1, name: "L"}
Unable to find error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is one thing you can do. Add the jquery script in the page instead putting it outside.

Comment: Yes Jai, application.js file contails jquery script and it is included using javascript_include_tag.

Comment: if mapbox.js is dependent on jquery then you have to place mapbox.js below jquery.

Comment: Yes Jai, i copied mapbox js into my project and added it below jquery in application.js file. but no luck.

Comment: I have the same problem with v3.0.1. For me, downgrading to v2.4.0 works fine.

Comment: I got it. It's my bad. I required a qr code scanner js file in application.js file and it contains a "L" global varible. It is overriding mapbox "L" object. I just modified L in qr js file and it works like charms. Thanks to Jai , tor Hovaland, Kristian Vybiral.

Answer (score 1):

Try linking to leaflet source script in the head.